# NUnit equivalent of JUnit's Rule

Tags: c#, nunit

Is there an equivalent of JUnit's Rule in C# ? I mean a way to avoid the repetition the same `[SetUp]` and `[TearDown]` lines in several different tests. Instead of:

```csharp
[SetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
    myServer.connect();
}

[TearDown]
public void TearDown()
{
    myServer.disconnect();
}
```

... put the logic in a rule that can be declared as field in several tests:

```java
public MyRule extends ExternalResource {
  @Override
  protected void before() throws Throwable
  {
    myServer.connect();
  };

  @Override
  protected void after()
  {
    myServer.disconnect();
  };
};
```

and then

```
class TestClass
{
    @Rule MyRule = new MyRule();
    ...
}
```

Comment: C# isn't a unit testing framework, just like JUnit isn't a language. There may be an equivalent of JUnit's `@Rule` annotation in whichever test framework you're using (or a different way of achieving the same result), but it's hard to tell because we only know the *language* you're using.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I use NUnit, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 5):

You could implement your own [`TestActionAttribute`](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=actionAttributes&r=2.6.4) class that runs your before- and after-test code. If you intend to perform the same action before and after every test, you can define your custom attribute at the class declaration.

e.g.:

```
[MyRule] // your custom attribute - applied to all tests
public class ClassTest
{
    [Test]
    public void MyTest()
    {
        // ...
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class MyRuleAttribute : TestActionAttribute
{
    public override void BeforeTest(TestDetails testDetails)
    {
        // connect
    }

    public override void AfterTest(TestDetails testDetails)
    {
        // disconnect
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NUnit works well with tests inheritance, so you can create a base test class with `SetUp` and `TearDown` methods:

```
[TestFixture]
public class BaseTest
{
    [SetUp]
    public virtual void SetUpTest()
    {
        //...
    }

    [TearDown]
    public virtual void TearDownTest()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Then create a regular test class that inherits from the base class and it will reuse the `SetUp` and `TearDown` implementations:

```
[TestFixture]
public class RegularTest : BaseTest
{
    [Test]
    public virtual void MyTest()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'd like to avoid. That kind of test inheritance tend to end badly with time.

Comment: @PhilippeBlayo Sorry, but your question states that you want to "avoid the repetition the same `[SetUp]` and `[TearDown]` lines in several different tests", which is precisely the point this answer addresses.

Comment: I don't know if you're aware of that, but tests you declare at BaseTest will be re-declared at RegularTest and you'll uselessly re-execute the same test. Bad practice. More reasons why inheritance is not the good answer : https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/unit-testing/3-reasons-why-we-should-not-use-inheritance-in-our-tests/

Comment: @neogineer Sure, declaring tests using inheritance is a bad practice. But if you read closely enough, the BaseTest in this answer does not declare any tests, only SetUp and TeardDown facilities, which is what this question is about.